# Cannot create a default constructor from a class that extends Dialog

Tags: java, android, dialog

I have a class that extends Dialog.  When I tried to generate my app, I got a message

`Error: This class should provide a default constructor (a public constructor with no arguments)`

I have tried `public myclass(){}`, but it doesn't work.  How can I define a default constructor?

Comment: first line of your constructor should be `super(context);`

Comment: Take a look at the API docs, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html
If you look at direct subclasses, such as AlertDialog, you can see the constructors those subclasses are Implementing. Maybe you are not implementing all the needed constructors?

Comment: What does " it doesn't work" mean?

Comment: @ELITE if i do as you said i have to make this  `public myclass(Context context){super(context);}` and i want to make a default constructor

Comment: @  Code-Apprentice  there is an error

Comment: it is probably a lint false-positive

Comment: post you code here...

Comment: Did you write your own constructor with parameters? You may have overridden the default constructor. If so you need to add a constructor without parameters.

Comment: Fixed grammar, spelling, and punctuation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### FIRST WAY

```
private static Context context;

public static void setContext(Context context_) {
    context = context_;
}

public myclass() {
    super(context);
}
```

> Note : Don't forget to call `setContext` method before going to call Constructor of this class.

### SECOND WAY

1) Create Application class in your project

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private static Context mContext;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mContext = getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        return mContext;
    }
}
```

2) Declare this Application in Manifest like below

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

3) And class `super` method in your class like

```
public myclass() {
    super(MyApplication.getContext());
}
```

Hope it'll help.

Comment: can't resolve symbol 'context' and i tried to declare it it said cannot reference it before supertype constructor has been called

Comment: change the constructor then...like `public myclass(Context context) {`, this will resolve the problem.

Comment: You have to create an Object of this class by passing `Context` to the constructor.

Comment: that will lead us to the begining that i need a default constructor that has no argument

Comment: ohh, sorry i forgot the main aim...you can achieve that using static `Context` object

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: You can achieve this in better way [here is how](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21818905/get-application-context-from-non-activity-singleton-class)

Comment: honestly I would really avoid keeping static reference to Context

Answer (score -1):

Try with adding default constructor like below...

```
public myclass(Context context){ 
  super(context);
}
```

Comment: you can't have that constructor.

Comment: it works  but if i do that doesn't that cause any problem during the program running