# Get Context in non-activity class multiple times

Tags: java, android, android-context

I'm working on an app where an "updater" constantly asks for data from a server. If it receives new data, the data is sent via LocalBroadcast to an activity. For this purpose I need the current Context which i pass in the constructor. Furthermore, the new data is written to a Singleton class (to store it trough the runtime of the app).

The problem is, that I need constantly new Context for my LocalBroadcast but its only passed one time in the constructor. Does someone have an idea of how  can I get the current context everytime the LocalBroadcast shall send something?

I found this answer but im always warned of putting context classes in static fields. ([Get application context from non activity singleton class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21818905/get-application-context-from-non-activity-singleton-class))

Thanks for reading and for every advice.
Here is my "Updater" Code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;

import java.util.Arrays;


public class ClientUpdater extends Thread {
    ClientCommunication cComm;              //this is my class which manages the Server-Client-Communication
    Intent BroadcastIntentUpdate;           //Intent for the LocalBroadcast
    Context cntxt;                          //stores the context passed in the constructor
    GlobalClass Obj1;                       //Instance of my Singleton

    public ClientUpdater(ClientCommunication cComm, Context context) {
        this.cComm = cComm;
        this.cntxt = context;
        BroadcastIntentUpdate = new Intent("update");
    }

    public void run(){
        while(true){

            String vomS1 = cComm.sendData("updateChat" + "~" + "$empty$");      //sends an update request to the server an receives the current chat-state
            if(!vomS1.equalsIgnoreCase("timeout")){

                Obj1 = GlobalClass.getInstance();
                String[] update = GlobalClass.decode(vomS1, ";");               //decodes the receives message                  
                String[] altchat = Obj1.getChat();                              //loads the stored chat protocoll from singleton


                if(!Arrays.equals(update, altchat)){                            //if the received message has new data...

                    BroadcastIntentUpdate.putExtra("message", update);
                    //for ".getInstance(cntxt)" the current Context is always needed right?
                    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(cntxt).sendBroadcast(BroadcastIntentUpdate);          //...it's sent to the activity
                    Obj1.setChat(update);                                                                                           //...and stored in the singleton
                }
            }    


            try {
                sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: "im always warned of putting context classes in static field"; There's no static field in that code; I don't generally deal with android so i can't say for sure (which is why I'm leaving a comment rather than an answer) but that code looks like it should be ultimately safe to use. There's a background task service in the android sdk, as far as I remember, I'd suggest using that rather than a thread. it should help with your context issue as well.

Comment: yes after your and HendraWDs comments I think about using a background service as well, thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
this.cntxt = context;
```

To

```
cntxt = context.getApplicationContext();
```

instead. Where `cntxt` is a static context. It will not create activity leak, since it uses application context.

It is better if you learn about background service in Android
https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If i write `cntxt = context.getApplicationContext();` is the cntxt variable always "refreshed" when used or do i misunderstand something? This would be what i need. And yes, you are right, background services are also a thing, maybe i will change that

Comment: using the application context is as it would suggest, it uses the context for the application. The context that you originally receive in your code is for the individual Receiver/UIComponent/Whatever that is supplying the context. The application context doesn't renew/refresh, but is always valid, nonetheless.

Comment: There are many things out there that you could use too instead of background service, like JobScheduler, FirebaseJobScheduler, AlarmManager, etc. I prefer FirebaseJobScheduler though. It will not always "refreshed", except you create the ClientUpdater  object, since it is reassigned from there. Although reassigned, the instance is the same. 1 android application has 1 application context instance, so it will not recreated except you close and re-open your app.