# Create AletDialog for an activity in another class [CONTEXT]

Tags: android, android-context

MainActivity [A]

```
    public class ViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        FilterDialogFragment.FilterListener,
        AffichageAdapter.OnAffichageSelectedListener {

   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_view);
           ButterKnife.bind(this);
```

Class [B]: i want to create a AlertDialogue when i click that its show in ViewActivity

```
public class AffichageAdapter extends FirestoreAdapter<AffichageAdapter.ViewHolder> {

AlertDialog.Builder Alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(What i Put here ! );
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49492474/how-to-use-get-getapplicationcontext-in-adapter-class/49492494#49492494

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `AffichageAdapter` class , you could declare a field like this:

```
private Context mContext;

public AffichageAdapter(Context context){
      this.mContext = context;//get context by constructor
}
```

and in `ViewActivity`

```
AffichageAdapter adapter = new AffichageAdapter(this);//"this" means ViewActivity, its a context.
xxx.setAdapter(adapter); // in some place.
```

then:

```
AlertDialog.Builder Alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
```

Answer (score 1):

YourClassName.this or `getContext()`

Comment: not work for me :'(

Comment: what is your idea btw? if you just want to open a custom dialog. try to read on `DialogFragment`

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to show alert from a different class in MainActivity A.
You should pass getContext() parameter from MainActivity to that Class B's show alert function.

Comment: when i create a method to get Context and i call it in second class that write " No static" and when i turn getContext to ( public static context ) that write  cannot referenced from static method